# Upgrade boot camp from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10

Tags: bootcamp, high-sierra, windows

I set up Boot Camp on my MBP (2014 model) installing Windows 8.1 (I want to use Windows 10, [which *is* supported](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990#models)) but the boot camp wizard did not seem to work with Windows 10 for some reason - possibly me choosing the wrong variant of Windows 10 from the MSDN page?

I tried the "Media Creation Tool" in windows to upgrade from 8.1 to 10 but this failed with a message about the tool not working for my version of windows.

I have downloaded a windows utility for creating a bootable USB using an ISO file. I then created an install USB for windows 10 on my USB drive. When booting and holding the option key, I see three options: Mac, Windows and the USB drive. If I select Windows it just boots as usual ignoring the USB drive. What happens if I select the USB drive? Will it install window 10 onto my windows bootcamp partition (as I want) or will it try to install it on the USB drive?

Comment: This page suggests otherwise: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990#models

Comment: And you have the latest version of the Boot Camp Assistant? And you have checked for software updates on your macOS and Windows 8.1 partition? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990

Comment: Are you attempting a clean install of Windows 10 from a USB installer? If so, you probably will need a Windows 10 license. Otherwise you will need to update from Windows 8.1 first, to get the free digital license, then preform a clean install of Windows 10. The license will automatically apply to the clean install.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I use windows 8.1, but I believe you can mount the Windows 10 iso. From there you can just click on the setup application and upgrade to Windows 10.

Some comments on what you are attempting.

- I understand you dowloadeded a windows utility to create the bootable USB. You make not mention copying the Windows Support Software to the USB. **This is required**.
- You see three options: Mac, Windows and the USB drive. The correct answer is "EFI Boot". I assume this is what you meant by USB drive.
- The Boot Camp Assistant creates the partitions necessary for the installation of Windows. You make no mention of creating space for the Windows partitions.
- All Microsoft "Media Creation Tool"s are incompatible with Apples way of installing windows. In other words, you should not use a Microsoft "Media Creation Tool" to create the USB Windows installer. You can use a Microsoft "Media Creation Tool" to download the Windows iso file.
- Your Mac already contains all the tools needed to create a USB Windows installer from an Windows iso file. You should use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Windows Support Software, but from there you can create the USB installer without the aid of the Boot Camp Assistant.
- Actually, you can install Windows 10 without using any USB drives. A procedure for this is given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306892/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2013-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant/307469#307469).

If you do not have working Windows 10 iso file and you have activated your Windows 8.1 installation, then you can upgrade to Windows 10 for free. This offer expires at the end of the year. You do have to agree that you use "assistive technologies". (Microsoft will not check to see if you do). The web site to see is: [Customers who use assistive technologies can upgrade to Windows 10 at no cost](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility/windows10upgrade?tduid=(14c348e893a91089cb2980533c6ee123)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-0FBZfNm6YPFXNhiu3o52rA)()).

Comment: How do I mount the Windows 10 ISO? Do I do that after booting into Windows 8.1?

Comment: Boot to Windows 8.1. Right click on the iso file. Choose Mount.

Comment: When I re-started in Windows 8.1 with the USB drive connected I was then able to click on the setup.exe from the USB drive and start the Windows update from there. This setup.exe was created by the MS utility I mentioned in the third paragraph of my question. This seems to have done the trick.