# Bootcamp not enough space

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, disk-space

I am trying to install Windows using bootcamp in my Mac (Mojave 10.14.3).

However, bootcamp tells me that I do not have enough disk space while in fact I have. 
I haven't got any local snapshots.
In fact OmniDiskSweeper tells me, that i have got 41.5 gb available.

The question is: Should i delete more files? Just saw a lot of answers like that, and as i understood, the only method is [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335076/bootcamp-not-enough-space-but-nothing-helps), but i haven't got flesh disk. And reinstalling macos is not a option.

Command:    diskutil info -all

```
   Device Identifier:         disk0
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk0
   Device / Media Name:       APPLE SSD SM0128L

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Not Supported

   Disk Size:                 121.3 GB (121332826112 Bytes) (exactly 236978176 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk0s1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0s1
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk0

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Partition Type:            EFI
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Volume UUID:               E783267B-A4C3-3556-B751-DBED770EB996
   Disk / Partition UUID:     5B422326-B5A8-4C8A-8D85-620AA9B1338D
   Partition Offset:          24576 Bytes (6 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                 314.6 MB (314572800 Bytes) (exactly 614400 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk0s2
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0s2
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk0

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Partition Type:            Apple_APFS
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Disk / Partition UUID:     ED3B37E3-C4EE-4315-ADEE-66BB3549A591
   Partition Offset:          314597376 Bytes (76806 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                 121.0 GB (121018208256 Bytes) (exactly 236363688 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk1
   Device / Media Name:       APPLE SSD SM0128L

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Disk / Partition UUID:     83008794-C170-47E2-BFAA-5586804F5533

   Disk Size:                 121.0 GB (121018208256 Bytes) (exactly 236363688 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Virtual:                   Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk1s1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1s1
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk1

   Volume Name:               Macintosh HD
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /

   Partition Type:            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Enabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       Yes
   Booter Disk:               disk1s2
   Recovery Disk:             disk1s3
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Volume UUID:               EC66991C-993D-4688-A333-A69667F6BB9F
   Disk / Partition UUID:     EC66991C-993D-4688-A333-A69667F6BB9F

   Disk Size:                 121.0 GB (121018208256 Bytes) (exactly 236363688 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        121.0 GB (121018208256 Bytes) (exactly 236363688 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Used Space:         80.8 GB (80787263488 Bytes) (exactly 157787624 512-Byte-Units) (66.8%)
   Volume Free Space:         40.2 GB (40230944768 Bytes) (exactly 78576064 512-Byte-Units) (33.2%)
   Allocation Block Size:     4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          No

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk1s2
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1s2
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk1

   Volume Name:               Preboot
   Mounted:                   No

   Partition Type:            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Disabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Booter Disk:               disk1s2
   Recovery Disk:             disk1s3
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Volume UUID:               70D5E6AB-4A3B-407E-A500-2FC2AE38C38A
   Disk / Partition UUID:     70D5E6AB-4A3B-407E-A500-2FC2AE38C38A

   Disk Size:                 121.0 GB (121018208256 Bytes) (exactly 236363688 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:         0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk1s3
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1s3
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk1

   Volume Name:               Recovery
   Mounted:                   No

   Partition Type:            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Disabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Booter Disk:               disk1s2
   Recovery Disk:             disk1s3
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Volume UUID:               868EDCAE-881B-418C-8DAB-0DDDA6231E80
   Disk / Partition UUID:     868EDCAE-881B-418C-8DAB-0DDDA6231E80

   Disk Size:                 121.0 GB (121018208256 Bytes) (exactly 236363688 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:         0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk1s4
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1s4
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk1

   Volume Name:               VM
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /private/var/vm

   Partition Type:            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Enabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Booter Disk:               disk1s2
   Recovery Disk:             disk1s3
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Volume UUID:               A16B7150-4A8C-463C-8F62-19CB78919719
   Disk / Partition UUID:     A16B7150-4A8C-463C-8F62-19CB78919719

   Disk Size:                 121.0 GB (121018208256 Bytes) (exactly 236363688 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        121.0 GB (121018208256 Bytes) (exactly 236363688 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Used Space:         80.8 GB (80787263488 Bytes) (exactly 157787624 512-Byte-Units) (66.8%)
   Volume Free Space:         40.2 GB (40230944768 Bytes) (exactly 78576064 512-Byte-Units) (33.2%)
   Allocation Block Size:     4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:           No
   Read-Only Volume:          No

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      No

**********

   Device Identifier:         disk2
   Device Node:               /dev/disk2
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk2
   Device / Media Name:       Disk Image

   Volume Name:               Boot Camp
   Mounted:                   No

   Content (IOContent):       None
   File System Personality:   ISO
   Type (Bundle):             cd9660
   Name (User Visible):       ISO 9660

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  Disk Image
   SMART Status:              Not Supported

   Disk Size:                 894.7 MB (894722048 Bytes) (exactly 1747504 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:         0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)

   Read-Only Media:           Yes
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Removable
   Media Removal:             Software-Activated

   Virtual:                   Yes

**********
```

Command: diskutil apfs list

```
   enAPFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 83008794-C170-47E2-BFAA-5586804F5533
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      121018208256 B (121.0 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   80792858624 B (80.8 GB) (66.8% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       40225349632 B (40.2 GB) (33.2% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 ED3B37E3-C4EE-4315-ADEE-66BB3549A591
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       121018208256 B (121.0 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 EC66991C-993D-4688-A333-A69667F6BB9F
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /
    |   Capacity Consumed:         77957672960 B (78.0 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 Yes (Unlocked)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 70D5E6AB-4A3B-407E-A500-2FC2AE38C38A
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         44326912 B (44.3 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 868EDCAE-881B-418C-8DAB-0DDDA6231E80
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         516968448 B (517.0 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 A16B7150-4A8C-463C-8F62-19CB78919719
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
        Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
        Capacity Consumed:         2147508224 B (2.1 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

Output from: diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 limits

```
Current Physical Store partition size on map:   121.0 GB (121018208256 Bytes)
  Minimum (constrained by file/snapshot usage):   83.6 GB (83589734400 Bytes)
  Recommended minimum (if used with macOS):       94.3 GB (94327152640 Bytes)
  Maximum (constrained by partition map space):   121.0 GB (121018208256 Bytes)
```

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac? What is the name of the Windows ISO file?

Comment: @DavidAnderson MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017), but why you asking about name of iso? Its official file from microsoft site.