# iMac-Pro(Win 10) NO Ethernet controller Driver (NO BOOTCAMP)

Tags: imac, windows, ethernet, driver

After successfully [installing WIN10 on my iMac-Pro without BOOTCAMP](http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/installing-windows-10-on-a-mac-without-bootcamp/), I was able to manually install the windows support(BOOTCAMP) drivers, and all of them work fine. Except the Ethernet Controller Driver, and that really bothers me since I'm not a fan of WiFi.

I have the iMac Pro base version

[image: DM]

I tried every Driver I could find with no success.

**Was any one able to get the Ethernet working on an iMac-Pro running WIN 10?**

Answer (score 1):

One of the first things I noticed about the article you link to is that there is no mention of a particular model or year Mac. It is **impossible** for there to be a one size fits all instructions for installing Windows on Mac computers. Second, the article is more than 2 years old. A lot has changed in two years. Any Macs capable of running High Sierra have had a firmware upgrade making many of the articles steps either obsolete or unnecessary.

Here a few comments with regard to the linked article.

- I assume you used your iMac Pro to download the Windows Support Software. Using a different Mac can lead to the wrong download.
- You do not need to use `unetbootin`. If fact, you do not even need a USB flash drive.
- Starting with with High Sierra, macOS no longer creates Hybrid partitioned drives. So, you should not have to use `gdisk`.
- The article does not mention System Integrity Protection (SIP). You should not have to disable SIP to install Windows.
- I assume your installation did not include a Window Recovery Environment partition. I assume this because the article did not provide the necessary steps to create one.
- The article included a step where the Windows Support Software (the legacy name is Boot Camp Support Software) is installed. Below is image taken from the article.

  [image: jj1]

  Note, there is a folder named `WindowsSupport`. This is a monumental error. If you have this folder on your flash drive, then I will assume this folder contains the folder named `$WinPEDriver$`. If so, then none of the Windows Support Software drivers needed properly install Windows were provided to the Windows installation software. If the `WindowsSupport` folder contains an `AutoUnattend.xml` file, then the Windows installation software did not receive any addition instructions provided by Apple to correctly install the Windows operating system.

  An example of how the files should appear in the root folder of the Windows installation media is shown below. This image was taken from [this Apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208495).

  [image: jj2]

You may want to refer the the question: [How to install Windows 10 into a 2013 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, USB flash drive or third party tools?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306892/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2013-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant) The accepted answer provides a few extra steps your article may have omitted.

Comment: Thanks for the replay(I guess), but it would seem that you are not familiar with the [iMac Pro](https://www.apple.com/imac-pro/). Although it's my first question here on Ask Different I had my share on StackExchange and I the question is valid as is, unless you see any other problem with it.

Comment: OK. I feel foolish. I had no idea there are iMac Pros. I stand corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the info... I didn't place the WindowsSupport folder correctly, but I planned to install it manually, and it did install the Drivers. Are you suggesting to reinstall the OS with the correct folder layout? Isn't there a way to just install the Ethernet controller on it's own(the one in the Drivers folder isn't accepted). Also BOOTCAMP wasn't able to partition the drive and failed(according to my search it was the APFS file system), and I wasn't able to install Mojave on MacOS Extended.

Comment: I suppose you could try having the Device Manager search the $WinPEDriver$ folder and subfolders for a ethernet driver. You can also try Windows Update and Apple Software Update.

Comment: By the way, you have not been installing Windows manually. You are not even close to a manual installation. Manually involves entering the installation commands into a Command Prompt window. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218105/is-it-possible-to-use-boot-camp-with-windows-10-from-an-external-hdd/307931#307931) for an example of a manual installation. Of course, these instructions would have to be adapted for an installation to an internal drive. Step 13 is where the drivers in the `$WinPEDriver$` folder are copied to the installation drive.

Answer (score -1):

He was talking about manually installing the drivers. I did the same thing with my regular 2013 iMac. What am I supposed to do if the same thing is happening for me but for wifi and audio? I can hear my mac if I plug something into the 3.5 mm port but otherwise the speakers won't play anything and my wifi isnt working either. It shows no connections and I tried so many Broadcom drivers and a couple Atheros drivers for it. I saw someone use Atheros 938x and that driver installed and didn't give a message about the controller unable to be turned on. So I'll work with that.
For ethernet, maybe try some Atheros ethernet drivers. Don't use the folder, go in device manager and select ethernet controller and right click it to update the driver. Then manually select drivers (don't use windows update or the driver search) and scroll for the ethernet controller drivers and try Atheros folder and Broadcom Connections Inc. or whatever it's called.

Comment: This isn't an answer but some hope.

Comment: It’s fine to post a partial answer. Removing some of the hypothetical questions will avoid down votes and adding links to what’s partially known usually generates positive votes. Thank you for trying to move the discussion forward and Welcome to Ask Different.