# Install Windows on Mac Without Bootcamp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I ran Windows on Mac using Bootcamp, but apparently I'm having so many compatibility issues, especially with this [eGPU](https://www.sonnettech.com/product/egfx-breakaway-puck560/overview.html).

So I was thinking to **manually install Windows** on my MacBook Pro 13" 2019, and check if this would allow my eGPU to work.
Apparently the eGPU works fine on both Windows and MacOS, but **it does NOT work on BootCamp**.

The problem must be with Bootcamp drivers, in fact the eGPU works fine in Windows. Instead it specifically says the eGPU does not work on Bootcamp (not on Windows, but on Bootcamp). So I am thinking installing Windows on a partition myself, with another boot loader rather than bootcamp, might help.

I have found [How to install Windows 10 into a 2013 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, USB flash drive or third party tools?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306892/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2013-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant) but the solution there is for a block size of 512. I need a solution for a block size of 4096.

Not looking for Virtual Machines solutions.

Comment: Using Bootcamp actually installs Windows in its own partition, so it‘s not clear what you actually want to do here. Can you clarify?

Comment: @nohillside BootCamp drivers may be the issue

Comment: So you just want to partition the disk and then install Windows directly into the empty partition? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I wanted to know the right boot loader I would need for this, I don't wanna use BootCamp again @nohillside

Comment: How would I boot into the partition otherwise? @nohillside

Comment: Boot Camp is may things. However, Boot Camp is **NOT** a boot loader.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying that David, however I don't get to choose the boot loader then and yet I think it is the issue @DavidAnderson

Comment: @nohillside Apparently that guid is for block size 512Bytes, I have 4096 and it says it should be a different procedure, would you please reopen the question?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Also, I would like NOT to have any BootCamp software in this new Windows Partition, this is my main question: may I create a custom partition myself and install an ISO image in it without using anything from BootCamp?

Comment: Have you tried Parallels Desktop?

Comment: @jmh I have Parallels but I need it to run on a partition, not on a VM :)

Comment: With the 1909 release of Windows, your Mac requires a driver from the Windows Support Software in order to access the internal drive. So I do not think no Boot Camp software is possible with this release. I do not know if the 2004 release of Windows includes a driver.

Comment: You mean no BootCamp software is compatible with that release? @DavidAnderson
If there is any driver I can download let me know, or any previous Windows version which might work with eGPU

Comment: You question was: may I create a custom partition myself and install an ISO image in it without using anything from BootCamp? My answer: No, if you use the 1909 release of Windows 10. I do not know if the same is true for the (current) 2004 release. You would have to try the release. Is there something stopping you from trying the 2004 release?

Comment: I guess I should just update from windows update and try. Also I was asking if there was a previous version which was known to work correctly: want it 1903? @DavidAnderson

Comment: What is stopping you from trying to install the latest release of Windows without the use of the drivers supplied by Apple? Set the T2 chip to allow booting from external devices. Copy the Windows ISO files to a ExFAT formatted flash drive. Reboot and hold down the option key. Select label `EFI Boot` under the external drive icon. Erase you current Windows installation by formatting the partition and reinstall Windows.

Comment: I’m gonna try now, I was trying to make a small partition rather than USB but I apparently it won’t let me create any partition... trying USB now

Comment: If you want an older version of Windows, there is a [website](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php). I do not know how reliable this website is.

Comment: @DavidAnderson What should I format the Windows Partition to? NTFS?

Comment: Because I can’t select any partition to install Windows to when booted on my USB with windows installer @DavidAnderson

Comment: Ok, I formatted the partition in NTFS but when I get to the Windows installer on the USB it won’t detect any driver to install Windows to @DavidAnderson

Comment: Also it won’t detect my keyboard and touchpad during installation, just the external mouse (I need to use disk part on the cmd) ideas? @nohillside

Answer (score 1):

Bootcamp just packages some drivers and saves you time from learning how to manage the boot process, there’s zero requirement to use it. The only hard step is on macs with T2 chips, you have to disable secure boot, so watch out for that.

I really like BootRunner since it saves me far more time than the cost to pay for my seat, but I also really like to keep dual booting. See if it saves you time before paying for it. For me the support for third party graphics cards was very appreciated.

- https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/boot-runner/

There is no one more knowledgeable that David Anderson and his posts are master classes in how to work with storage on Mac hardware. [How to install Windows 10 into a 2013 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, USB flash drive or third party tools?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306892/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2013-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant)

I would put in a smaller drive temporarily so you can vet his instructions on 512 block size if you can’t wait for him or someone with his skill to do the math if you can’t figure out which items in his recipe need an adjustment.

Comment: So it does support eGPU?

Comment: Also, I have T2 chip, but I can disable curtail while doing any set required

Comment: Yeah - I read you as 2009. Initially, I fixed that - thanks. I don’t have that eGPU to test. If someone wants to send me the gear to test, I would gladly. Sorry for the error @FET  - my hunch is you’ll spend less time with the bootcamp drivers and identifying what to add rather than starting new, but I haven’t the gear to test that out.

Comment: I am checking this guide at the moment: https://egpu.io/boot-camp-egpu-setup-guide/
If this fails I shall check that guide again and see what needs to be changed for 4096 bytes

Comment: I shall keep you updated, if these guides fail I am calling anyway Sonnet' Support tomorrow :)